# How to connect wireless mouse with iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, bluetooth

I am using iOS 4.

I am wondering that is it possible to connect a wireless mouse with iphone via bluetooth? Yesterday I saw a remote access/login to mac pc through the iphone and ipad but its seems hard to operate it as there were no mouse and keyboard.

So, I want to know that is there any way to connect wireless mouse with iphone so it make easy to use when we want to use remote login?

Is there any API that help to develop this kind of application?

Comment: It's been done a while back: http://www.engadget.com/2010/01/04/iphone-and-magic-mouse-linked-up-by-btstack-video/

Comment: yeah but application need jailbreaked phone !!!

Comment: You're not able to do that without a jailbroken device or external, Apple-approved accessory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order for a mouse to be available over bluetooth, it would need to be MFi compliant, which requires an MFi authenticator chip in the mouse.

Unless you market an accessory yourself (and receive Apple's blessing), it simply will not work.

Answer (score 5):

You should just try to connect a standard Bluetooth wireless mouse to the iPhone and try, as per the apple supported Bluetooth profiles, the iPhone 4 supports HID profile , which means that Bluetooth wireless key boards and mice should work 
See this for reference - http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3647

Comment: **However** further down the page you mentioned, they note that their interpretation of HID covers only bluetooth keyboards, not mice.

Comment: yes - noticed that it does not mention mice, I think that as far as apple is concerned the mouse era is over

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. There's lots of things that can easier be done using a mouse, a fact they are propably aware of since they need to work with their own stuff too. As for their designed-as-touch-devices though they're eager to keep them uncontaminated with mouse-pointers...

Answer (score 3):

To do this you either need to Jailbreak your device or make a accessory yourself. No accessory will be able to to use a mouse in apples applications or the home screen unless your device is jailbroken.  You can make a accessory yourself but you have to apply for the MFi Program (http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) but developers would have to build the functionality into their app so you couldn't use it on any app.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the API.  It is not possible to use a wireless mouse with a iPad however if you were part of the MFi program you could make a mouse with a 30 pin iPhone connecter on the end which a developer could communicate with.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the crux loaded.  Unfortunately it's for iPad and not iPhone but if you have a iPad it looks awesome. Check it out at http://cruxcase.com/products/crux-loaded-2/. It's kinda expensive :(